# Why can't I push to list - kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I can't push to list of audio. **Important: I don't want to change listOf to mutableListOf**

```
private var offlineAudioList: List<Audio> = listOf(Audio())
val audio = Audio(
                    _id = cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
                    ), filePath = cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH)
                    ), title = cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)
                    ), duration = cursor.getInt(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)
                    ), writer = User(
                        image = cursor.getString(
                            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID)
                        )
                    )
                )
offlineAudioList.plus(audio)
```

This doesn't work though audio is not null. When I log audio, it gives me a class with data, so it's not the problem.

Comment: You're not reassigning `offlineAudioList`.

Comment: what do you think `plus` does? (hint: if you are not sure, read the doc)

Answer (score 1):

When working with read-only List in a `var` variable or property, to change it you have to reassign to the variable/property because “adding” to it with `plus()` is actually creating a new List instance:

```
offlineAudioList = offlineAudioList.plus(audio)

// or

offlineAudioList = offlineAudioList + audio

// or

offlineAudioList += audio
```

Also, where you declared your list it looks like you could have used `emptyList()` instead of `listOf(Audio())` unless there is some purpose to your list having a blank Audio item in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with an Immbutable list (`List<T>`) you cannot push or remove values from the list. When you do `plus` or `listA + listB` a new `MutableList` is created and then the values from both lists appended, but you don't really see it. Usually AndroidStudio/IntelliJ give you warnings out because it's an expensive operation. (More than having a `MutableList`)

[Proof here below from Kotlin's open source repo in github](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt)
[image: Proof]

Something that you could do but I dislike:

```kotlin
private var offlineAudioList: List<Audio> = listOf(
    Audio(),
    Audio(
        _id = cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
         ), 
        filePath = cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH)
        ), 
        title = cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)
        ), 
        duration = cursor.getInt(
            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)
        ), 
        writer = User(
            image = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID)
            )
        )
   )
)
```

**I highly encourage you to wrap this "construction" of the audio object into a function**

Comment: note that the fact that `plus` happens to return a mutable list is an implementation detail, and not relevant to the caller, since the return type is `List`, which doesn't include mutating methods